# When does the New Years Eve hat award?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winterbash

The description of the "New Years Eve" hat states:

> Post an upvoted question or answer on December 31

I've clearly posted [multiple](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44861/29) [answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44900/29) that got upvoted today, yet the hat didn't award yet.

Is this by design, with the hat only awarding on in the new year, if you've met the requirements in the old year, or is it a bug and should the hat be awarded already?

Comment: Are you sure you posted them today UTC? As SE works on that time zone.

Comment: @RonanForman Yes, I've added links to the answers.

Comment: I've already gotten it, but it took the better part of an hour for me too. The job that awards this hat is probably just slow because having an upvoted post isn't really a volatile condition.

Comment: It took a while for it to pop for me, but eventually it did. I waited about an hour.

Comment: I'm actually waiting on several hats to pop at the moment. Something just seems sluggish.

Comment: I got it almost instantly... for a *question* though, don't know if that's important.

Comment: I also missed it on [an answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44925/4775) that should have qualified

Comment: I don't have it either.

Comment: I just received mine.

Comment: Just got mine too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scheduler service wasn't restarted after the [security update](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-100.mspx) caused a reboot of the server, so no hats were awarded since then. I have restarted it (and also set it to always be started automatically), so a huge bunch of hats just got awarded. Sorry about that!

Comment: I assume this is also the reason that I [just got my Santa hat](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3684/did-santa-skip-me)?

Comment: Yes, that would be it.