# Did Santa skip me?

Tags: support, winterbash

I only posted [once](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43875/5029) on Christmas, and it only now got upvoted.  Am I too late for the Santa hat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed in the meantime, this coincides with the issue at [When does the New Years Eve hat award?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3677). You weren't too late – it's only important that you posted on December 25, not when it was upvoted –, it's just that at the moment you received that upvote, the scheduler was already broken (as explained in the other post). You received your hat when that was repaired.